# Deploying own Docker Registry: Registry restarting

Tags: permissions, docker, ssl-certificate, docker-registry

I know Docker Hub, and I know you can create your own repositories on it.
But you have to pay when you want to create multiple private repo's.
So I want my own Docker Registry Server using self signed certificates.

I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)
So these are the steps:
Create certificates in certs/

```
mkdir -p certs && openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
```

So this creates a domain.key and domain.cert in my certs/.
Now it's time to start my docker registry (using the keys):

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

After the deploy I see this:
$ docker ps

```
 "/bin/registry /etc/d"   12 seconds ago      Restarting (1) 1 seconds ago   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

My docker logs are telling me:

```
time="2015-12-11T10:18:19Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=ee1b0d64-89eb-4be7-bc3e-e0e249bf117d version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-11T10:18:19Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=ee1b0d64-89eb-4be7-bc3e-e0e249bf117d version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-11T10:18:19Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.5.2 instance.id=ee1b0d64-89eb-4be7-bc3e-e0e249bf117d version=v2.2.1 
time="2015-12-11T10:18:19Z" level=fatal msg="open certs/domain.crt: permission denied"
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue with SELinux and Docker:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t ~/certs/
```